# lines function not working as expected

Tags: haskell

In Prelude, unlines work as expected. Below is the example

```
GHCi>unlines ["aa","bb","bb"]
"aa\nbb\nbb\n"
```

But why does lines not work. Even the type signature says that it can only take numbers.

```
GHCi>:t lines
lines :: Num t => [t]
```

So, if I try

```
GHCi>lines "aa\nbb\nbb\n"
```

why do I get an error? Is there a lines that I need to import?

Regards,

Comment: What does `GHCi>:i lines` give you? That should show where the `lines` you're seeing is defined.

Comment: In GHCi it says `lines :: String -> [String]`. So you have imported a different `lines.

Comment: Yes mine shows GHCi>:i lines
lines :: Num t => [t]   -- Defined at <interactive>:14:1. Can you please tell me how I can get the correct one?

Comment: Thanks I fixed it, i just restarted it and it works fine.

Comment: When GHCi says "Defined at <interactive>:14:1", it means that `lines` was re-defined in GHCi (input line 14). Hence, you are not using the standard `lines`.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure that you are not shadowing the `lines` function:

```
:t lines
lines :: String -> [String]
```

Make sure you have not define a `lines` variable.
As @ChadGilbert mention you can use `:i`